# display html page from database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I insert the html string into the DB. Then I load that string in webview and it
display `null` only. Please help me. Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     WebView browser;
    private static String inp;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         browser=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.w1);


         // browser.loadDataWithBaseURL("x-data://base",inp,"text/html", "UTF-8",null);
         browser.loadData(inp, "text/html", "UTF-8"); 



    }
    public void insertUndergraduate(){
        AndroidOpenDbHelper androidOpenDbHelperObj = new AndroidOpenDbHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase = androidOpenDbHelperObj.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        inp = "<html>"+"<body><h1>hai mohan</h1></body>"+"</html>";
        contentValues.put(AndroidOpenDbHelper.COLUMN_NAME_PAGE,inp);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't set `inp` before `browser.loadData(inp, "text/html", "UTF-8");`

Comment: @MohanViswa where do you do `inp = ` before `browser.loadData()`? You can't expect it to be anything if you don't set it somewhere.

Comment: where i want set that string variable

Comment: ya it dispaly the page.how to find that string it insert into db or not